# Show a sum in a Banach space is convergent and bounded

Tags: banach-spaces, inner-products, convolution, absolute-convergence

> $f,g \in l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |f(n)|^2 < \infty, \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |g(n)|^2 < \infty$.
> Show that $(f \star g)(n) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} f(m)g(-m+n)$ is convergent and a bounded function of n.

I am not quite sure how to show this but think the first step would be to write $(f \star g)(n)$ as an inner product. Can anyone help with this and also is there an example of $f \star g$ that isn't in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Try showing that $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}|f(m)g(-m+n)|<\infty$ by using Hölder's inequality for the counting measure.

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The quantity is the inner product $\langle f,h\rangle,$ where $h(m)=g(n-m),$ $n$ fixed.

Answer (score 2):

We will answer the question at the very end of OP. The problem becomes simpler if we may use the Fourier series. For $F\in L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ let
$$\widehat{F}(n)={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)e^{-inx}\,dx$$ The space  $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ is unitarily isomorphic to   $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ by the mapping
$U(F)= \{\widehat{F}(n)\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty.$ If $F,G\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ then $FG\in L^1(-\pi,\pi).$ It can be shown that
$\widehat{F}*\widehat{G}=\widehat{FG}.$
Hence the question is equivalent to the following: find $F,G\in L^2$ such that $FG\notin L^2.$ Let $F(x)=G(x)=|x|^{-1/4}.$ Then $F\in L^2,$ but $F^2\notin L^2.$ The corresponding sequences are given by
$$f(n)=g(n)={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi |x|^{-1/4}e^{-inx}\,dx$$

Comment: @AnneBauval I have answered the very last part of the question. I will point it clearly in the text. Thanks

Comment: @AnneBauval No problem. Myself I am very careless these days: answering questions while watching Roland Garros.